# error 10055: 'no buffer space available' while populating database

Tags: python, mongodb, sockets, python-3.x, urllib

I am currently using python 3.4 and am getting an error 10055 when running my code. The code is below.

I have tried putting a "time.sleep(10)" and it that allows my database to gather more entries, but eventually my program always gets the error.

I understand that when I "sock.close()" my socket, the socket doesn't actually close, it lingers for a while before closing, and that is what is causing my error.

I am unable to find a way to force the connection closed in order to free up sockets and run the program to completion.

I have many methods in my code, but these are the ones that would be related to my errors, if you want the whole code, just let me know.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import time

# Connect to MongoDB
def database_connection():
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
    MONGODB_PORT = 27017
    DBS_NAME = 'SEC'
    COLLECTION_NAME = 'Form15F'
    connection = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    return collection, connection

# Connection to the .XML online link
def connection(xml_link):
    import socket
    # Make xml_link readable so it can be manipulated
    sock = urlopen(xml_link)
    xml_readable = sock.read()
    sock.close()
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_readable)
    return root

# Populate database
def database_addition(Holdings_FundName, Holdings_Name, Holdings_Shares, Holdings_Value, Holdings_Date):
    for i in range(len(Holdings_Name)):
        dictionary = {'Date':Holdings_Date[i] ,'Fund Name':Holdings_FundName[i],'Holding Company':Holdings_Name[i], 'Number of Shares':Holdings_Shares[i], 'Value of Shares':Holdings_Value[i]}
        db, dbc = database_connection()
        db.insert(dictionary)
        dbc.close()

def main(link):
    all_xml_docs = fund_listings(link)
    for i in all_xml_docs:
        Fund_Name, date, xml_link = fund_details(i)
        print(Fund_Name)
        print(xml_link)
        Holdings_FundName, Holdings_Name, Holdings_Shares, Holdings_Value, Holdings_Date = holdings_attributes(xml_link, Fund_Name, date)
        database = database_addition(Holdings_FundName, Holdings_Name, Holdings_Shares, Holdings_Value, Holdings_Date)
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I see a few function but not how they are called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was within the amount of times I kept connecting and disconnecting from the MongoDB. I changed the database_addition function and that removed the problem.
I have posted both ways the function can be changed in order to remove this problem. The first, is changing the position of connecting to the database before and outside the for loop. The second is to use bulk_insert in order to Populate the database.

```
# Populate database
def database_addition(Holdings_FundName, Holdings_Name, Holdings_Shares, Holdings_Value, Holdings_Date):
    db, dbc = database_connection()
    for i in range(len(Holdings_Name)):
        dictionary = {'Date':Holdings_Date[i] ,'Fund Name':Holdings_FundName[i],'Holding Company':Holdings_Name[i], 'Number of Shares':Holdings_Shares[i], 'Value of Shares':Holdings_Value[i]}
        db, dbc = database_connection()
        db.insert(dictionary)
    dbc.close()
```

insert_bulk:

```
# Bulk insert
def database_addition_bulk(attribute_list):
    db,dbc = database_connection()
    db.insert_many([{'Date':attribute_list[0][i], 'Fund Id':attribute_list[1][i], 'Fund Name':attribute_list[2][i],'Holding CUSIP':attribute_list[3][i], 'Holding Name':attribute_list[4][i], 'Number of Shares':attribute_list[5][i], 'Value of Shares':attribute_list[6][i]} for i in range(len(attribute_list[0]))])
    dbc.close()
```